# How to print images to scale using HTML, CSS and Javascript?

Tags: html, css, image, printing, scaling

**Background:** My team currently provides a set of services that result in an image containing a few barcodes. A regulatory third party holds us to quality standards on our barcodes. Upon delivery of our image to our client we use a Java applet to gain access to system level details regarding printers. The end result is a image printed to precises scale regardless of printer/browser/OS (assuming the client has Java SE).

**Issue:** Chrome will soon be deprecating [NPAPI](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/npapi-deprecation) i.e. no more applets :)

**Research:** Thus far I have experimented with a basic web app that uses CSS @media screen{}, @media print{} and @page rule. Although I have had moderate success in the scaling the printed result I am noticing that my results vary greatly when moving from browser to browser.

Application / OS scaling seems to be a major issue as of now (something I can get around with PDF's using printer preferences)

Some of the CSS I am toying with below...

```css
@page {
  size: 8.5in 11in;
  margin: 0in orphans: 0;
  widows: 0:
}
@media print {
  .print_medium_image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0in;
    left: 0in;
    width: 7.625in;
    height: 10.4in;
    margin-top: 0in;
    margin-left: 0in;
    margin-bottom: 0in;
    margin-right: 0in;
  }
```

Note** - I am working in parallel on a PDF solution, which I have already proved to work.

**Q: How to use standard web tools to print precisely scaled images regardless of browser / printer / OS**  - Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I sense a question is coming somewhere but I cannot find it yet

Comment: Edit for clarity - @ochi

Comment: Are you OK with using back-end solutions? I am thinking of http://weasyprint.org/ but not sure if that's in the scope of what you are seeking